# Unsubscibe from firestore onSnapshot listener when the user just exits from the app

Tags: ionic3, google-cloud-firestore

I was facing problem while I'm trying to implement unsubscribe on firestore onSnapshot listener. The problem is while I'm try to override the functionally of back button the back button doesn't closes the app, moreover I'm not sure that it unsubscribes from the onSnapshot listener,and if it unsubscribes , then how to close the app.

code what I tried:

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(() =>{
        customer.unsubscribe();
      })
```

```
 this.unsubscribe = this.db.collection(this.collectionName).orderBy('name')
    .where("deleted","==",false)
    .onSnapshot(customerSnapshot =>{
```

clarification: here customer is provider  and unsubscribe is a data member in customer provider.

**Note:** I don't want any confirmation from user regarding closing the app, so no alert controls

**Also:** Does firebase provides any mechanism through we can verify that the subscription has been detached .

Thanks

Comment: It's typically best to do such unsubscribing in a [lifecycle method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/lifecycle/angular), such as `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically best to unsubscribe your database listeners in a [lifecycle method](https://ionicframework.com/docs/lifecycle/angular), such as `ionViewWillLeave` or `ionViewDidLeave`. Most commonly you'd unsubscribe in the method that is the opposite of where you subscribed. So if you attach your listeners in `ionViewWillEnter`, unsubscribe them in `ionViewDidLeave`.

Once you've call the unsubscribe method and it returns, the listener has been removed. But there is no way to see from a unsubscribe method whether it's been called, so you will have to track that yourself.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer, but I tried using this(after posting this Q), but I am not sure that the listener was unsubscribed.How do I keep track of it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. In the code you posted, you can set `this.unsubscribe` to `null` after you called it. But you're subscribing in `ionViewWillEnter`, and unsubscribe in `ionViewDidLeave`, there little use in doing so, as the code is already balanced. If all of this is not helping you, consider describing what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve, as right now I have a feeling we're looking at a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sir, I was simply trying to unsubscribe from the listener, in the Q I posted , I had shown that I tried unsubscribing it when the user press back button to exit the app, but in that case the back button doesn't work ,and moreover the suggestion you gave , I did tried that , but I was not sure that, how do I check that the unsubscribe has been done successfully?

Comment: At this point I can only repeat what I've said before: if you call the unsubscribe method, and the call returns, then the unsubscribe succeeded. If there are problems, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Sorry for asking again,it might sound silly, as I completely new to this , unsubscribe thing, so the thing what I concluded from ur help is , that I should put the unsubscribe in a if probably and check if it returns true..? One last thing which might again sound silly but if I don't unsubscribe does it affect the read/write counts ?